# How to properly set underline type under Cocoa

Tags: macos, styles, nstextview

ALL,

```
NSMutableDictionary* constattrs = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
[attrs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:( NSUnderlinePatternDot )] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
[attrs setValue:style.GetUnderlineColour() forKey:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName];
[m_textView setTypingAttributes:attrs];
```

Code above compiles fine and executes, but the text in the view does not become underlined.

I'm testing under OSX 10.13 with the minimum required of 10.9.

What am I missing?

TIA!

[EDIT]:

```
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, end-start);

    NSTextStorage* storage = [m_textView textStorage];
    if( style.HasFontUnderlined() )
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:( NSUnderlinePatternDot )] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
        [dict setValue:style.GetUnderlineColour() forKey:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName];

        [storage addAtributes:dict range:range];
        [dict release];
```

I'm getting compilation warning on the code above:

```
warning: instance method '-addAtributes:range:' not found (return type defaults to 'id'); did you mean '-addAttributes:range:'? [-Wobjc-method-access]
```

Can you help?

[/EDIT]

Comment: Do you want to underline existing text? Does `NSUnderlineStyleSingle` work?

Comment: @Willeke, no - the text that will be written to the view

Comment: How do you write text to the view?

Comment: @Willeke, I'm calling `[m_textView insertText:wxCFStringRef <params>].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the underline style.

```
[attrs setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:( NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternDot )] forKey:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName];
```

Comment: That works - thank you. Could you pleaae look at my edit and see what am I missing? TIA!

Comment: @NV, I guess my eyes are not that bright anymore. I accepted the answer.